# Continuous scrolling slider in a same direction using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jcarousel, carousel

I am using jquery  [Tiny Carousel](http://www.baijs.nl/tinycarousel/) for sliding images but our client asks for continuous scrolling in a same direction i searching it for a day and i cant found the exact thing... Did anyone here came across it?

Now i am using this plugin for tinycarousel

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function () {
          jQuery("#slider").tinycarousel({ axis: 'x', display: 1, interval: true })
         });
</script>
```

and i found that with this the looping is not possible anyone know how to loop this? or point me an another slider jquery control....

Comment: Same direction means, you want to disable the scrolling in other direction?

Comment: yes scrolling like left to right with a constant speed

Comment: Are you going to have infinite images? what if you reach the last image?

Comment: Would appreciate if you share some code with us?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: yes infinite looping

Comment: try `http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/plugins.html#autoscroll`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found the slider here

http://javascript.about.com/library/blcmarquee1.htm

Answer (score 2):

I do this

in jquery.tinycarousel.js Search for function initialize () and replace

```
iSteps = Math.max(1, Math.ceil(oPages.length / options.display) - iLeftover);
```

with

```
iSteps = 9999999999999999999999999;
```

**OR**
in jquery.tinycarousel.min.js Search for

```
u=Math.max(1,Math.ceil(k.length/e.display)-x);
```

and replace with `u = 9999999999999999999999999;`

Then

put this code in document ready

```
    $('#slider1').tinycarousel({'display':3});  
    var SliderLength = $('#slider1 .viewport li').length;//set li or img or what ever
    var append = $('#slider1 .viewport > ul').html();//grab the curent items
    $('.buttons.next').mouseup(function()
    {//next button click event
        $('#slider1 ul').append(append);//append those item 

        var sliderWidth = parseInt($('#slider1 .overview').width());
        var curLength = parseInt($('#slider1 li').length);
        $('#slider1 .overview').width((sliderWidth * (curLength / SliderLength) ));//update content width
    });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4CmFC/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [demo using the jQuery.carouFredSel-plugin](http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/23/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="carousel">
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit1.png" alt="fruit1" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Apple</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit2.png" alt="fruit2" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Mandarin</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit3.png" alt="fruit3" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Banannas</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit4.png" alt="fruit4" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Cherries</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit5.png" alt="fruit5" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Orange</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit6.png" alt="fruit6" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Melon</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit7.png" alt="fruit7" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Lemon</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit8.png" alt="fruit8" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Grapes</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit9.png" alt="fruit9" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Peach</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit10.png" alt="fruit10" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Pear</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit11.png" alt="fruit11" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Strawberry</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/fruit12.png" alt="fruit12" width="200" height="200" />
            <span>Melon</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {

    var $c = $('#carousel'),
        $w = $(window);

    $c.carouFredSel({
        align: false,
        items: 10,
        scroll: {
            items: 1,
            duration: 2000,
            timeoutDuration: 0,
            easing: 'linear',
            pauseOnHover: 'immediate'
        }
    });


    $w.bind('resize.example', function() {
        var nw = $w.width();
        if (nw < 990) {
            nw = 990;
        }

        $c.width(nw * 3);
        $c.parent().width(nw);

    }).trigger('resize.example');

});
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
}
body * {
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #333;
    line-height: 22px;
}

#wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
#carousel {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
#carousel div {
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#carousel div img {
    border: none;
}
#carousel div span {
    display: none;
}
#carousel div:hover span {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$(function(){

var current = 1;
var totalImages = $("#slider-code li").size();
var oSlider = $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({        
    animation:false,
    controls: false
});

$('#nextButton').click(function(){
     current += 1;
    if(current > totalImages){
     current = 1;   
    }
     oSlider.tinycarousel_move(current);          
});
```

});​

and here is the demo in [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/hu3v8/1/)

Comment: I see the fiddle when all the rightside images are shown it again go scrolls on leftside and comes on right direction.... any way to make it loop...?

Comment: @krish what do you mean by loop? did you mean that when the first set of pictures are shown, the set should be shown in the reverse direction?

Comment: :i mean they should move on in a same direction like the way 1->2->3->4->1->2->3.....and so on

Comment: @krish in the demo it moves like so.

Comment: @suhair. I does NOT move. It 'jumps' ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I coded in a situation like yours. This scrolls up, but you can easily modify it to scroll in any direction. Change the algorithm from marginTop modification to:

- marginTop increase by 1, for up to down scroll
- marginLeft increase by 1, for left to right scroll
- marginLeft decrease by 1, for right to left scroll

  ```
  (function($)
  {
      var ScrollMe = function(element)
  {
         var elem = $(element);
         var obj = this;

         elem.wrapInner("<div class='mbui_scrollable'></div>");
         var scr=elem.children("div.mbui_scrollable");

         setInterval($(this).scrollUp,130); //CHANGE HERE FOR SPEED
     };
     $.fn.scrollme = function()
     {
         return this.each(function()
         {
             var element = $(this);
             // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
             if (element.data('scrollme')) return;
             // pass options to plugin constructor
             var myplugin = new ScrollMe(this);
             // Store plugin object in this element's data
             element.data('scrollme', myplugin);
         });
     };
     $.fn.scrollUp = function(elem)
     {
          var allObj=$(".mbui_scrollable");
          for(i=0;i<allObj.length;i++)
          var s=$(allObj[i]).css('marginTop');
              var n=parseInt(s)-1;            //CHANGE HERE TO CHANGE DIRECTION AND SPEED
              var h=$(allObj[i]).css('height');
              if((n*-1)>=parseInt(h))
                  n=$(allObj[i]).parent().css('height');
              $(allObj[i]).css('marginTop',n);
     };})(jQuery);
  ```

Apply to elements like:

```
$(".scroll").scrollme();
```

Answer (score 0):

For my iPhone app's website ([niwuzzles.com](http://niwuzzles.com)) I used Alen Grakalic's jQuery plugin EasySlider to accomplish this.

Project Description:
http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

Continuous Slide demo:
http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/01.html

Code Example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){   
            $("#slider").easySlider({
                auto: true, 
                continuous: true
            });
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider">
            <ul>                
                <li><img src="img1.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="img2.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="img3.png" /></li>
                <li><img src="img4.png" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to Tiny Carousel to add looping. I just picked up on some stuff from the timed sliding function.

http://pastebin.com/3M3akv9r

Answer (score 0):

i think it must work

```
$('#slider1').tinycarousel({start: 2,
         interval: true 
        });
```